# Stop hairparticles going through hat object in Blender 2.9

Tags: modeling, modifiers, particles, hair, makehuman

**Problem:**
I have this human model which I made hair from using this tutorial:
[Blender 2.93 Tutorial: How To Make Realistic Looking Hair](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i9ZwY.jpg) by
*Chipper Videos*.

But the hair keeps going through the hat. How do I solve it?

**What I tried:**
I tried the *Vertex Weight Proximity* modifier and the "length" thing in the particular section of Blender assigning it to the vertex group of the hair.
But it either hides it when the hat is both on and off the body. Or does NOT hide the hair at all and keeps going through the hat.

*What did I do wrong? & How do I solve it?*

P.S: Screenshots of my model for a better understanding of the hair sticking through the hat:

[image: human model with hair sticking through the hat.]

Someone on Twitter did give me a direction on what to do and also explained the *Vertex Weight Proximity* modifier. Here is the [Twitter link](https://twitter.com/RayMairlot/status/1501279474050027527?t=_TgeTyOZaU5pnmV1cv2wOg&s=19) if you're still curious.

Comment: What is *"the Vertical Weight Proximitry"*?

Comment: @Blunder Someone on Twitter did give me a direction on what to do and also explained the Verti- Oh I just see It is VERTEX and not vertical, however here is the twitterlink if you're still curious: https://twitter.com/RayMairlot/status/1501279474050027527?t=_TgeTyOZaU5pnmV1cv2wOg&s=19

Comment: Ah ok :-) The *Vertex Weight Proximity* modifier should do the trick. But your character would need 2 particle hair systems. One for the top hair and one for the side hair that is still visible when he wears the hair. Are there 2 particle systems? And which settings have you used for the modifier? Maybe you can share the file?

Comment: @Blunder At some parts of the hair I have Two or even three partical systems. However most of the planes have 1 partical system. For the modifer settings I used the basic one of Low and High as it's default. I did try to mess around with it by changing it to 0,0001 for example but didn't see differences and places it back to the defaults.